# require once issue in php

Tags: php, pear, require-once

I am using xampp to develop my php application.  Few days back I installed pear ti use DB abstraction.  After that, I couldn't use include files from parent directory, however I can include from sub-driectories.

Here is what I see when I check my include path

.;E:\xampp\php\PEAR

I tried changed include path using set_include_path to the location where my files are stored, then the application failed to load Pear files.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: How are you including the files?

Comment: @deceze the file I am trying to inclde resides in /htdocs/sms/application/configs/application.php,  I am calling this file from /htdocs/sms/cce_desc/index.php and the code is require_once "../application/configs/application.php";

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to prepend to the include path stack is...

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    'path/to/app/includes',
    'path/to/any/other/includes',
    get_include_path()
)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have got this (include_path='E:\xampp\htdocs\sms;.;E:\xampp\php\PEAR')  but still failed to include file

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use set_include_path, you can do it like this:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.'path_to_parent');
```

Use the predefined constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR in case your code moves to a server that uses a different directory separator.

Personally if I needed to set the path specially for a particular site, I would try to set the path in the .htaccess file in the site's web root. It provides a more obvious place to look for site-wide configurations like the include_path. Here is the line you would put in the .htaccess file:

```
php_value include_path ".;E:\xampp\php\PEAR;path_to_parent"
```

or on a Linux server:

```
php_value include_path ".:some_path/PEAR:path_to_parent"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, created a .htaccess file in my root dir.  This is my parent directory path "E:\xampp\htdocs\sms" so I set avalue as follows php_value include_path ".;E:\xampp\php\PEAR;E:\xampp\htdocs\sms" .  But it didn't work.  The I changed value to include_path "E:\xampp\htdocs\sms" and it is working.  But I need both values there.